# Querystring for searching content in several paths, using SQL2

Tags: aem, jcr-sql2

Currently I am stuck at the issue to generate a query with multiple paths. I could accomplish the situation searching for childnodes from a specific *single* rootpath in the crx repository. I use the keyword `isdecendantnodenode()` for that:

```
select * from [nt:base] as p
where
   (isdescendantnode (p, [first path])) 
   and contains(p.*, '"bankproducts"')
   and p.[sling:resourceType] = 'components/content/download'
```

As I said this works fine. Now I have to face the challenge searching for elements that does appear in *two or more* different childnodes - in the same hierarchy level.

My attempts to achieve that are following:

```
select * from [nt:base] as p
where
   (isdescendantnode (p, [first path]) and isdescendantnode(p, [second path]))
   and contains(p.*, '"bankproducts"')
   and p.[sling:resourceType] = 'components/content/download'
```

This gives me only the elements back they are only in the second path (in my eyes).

The next example results into a repository exception:

```
select * from [nt:base] as p
where
   (isdescendantnode (p, ([first path] and [second path]))
   and contains(p.*, ' "bankproducts"')
   and p.[sling:resourceType] = 'components/content/download'
```

May the order of keywords are wrong. I run out of ideas so SO belongs to the last options I've got.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to find elements in first path and second path, for example, en and de branches? In that case, you need use 'OR' in the path condition -- (isdescendantnode (p, [first path]) or isdescendantnode(p, [second path])). Ingore my comment if you are not looking for it.

Comment: @Kleenstar I need a query for AND and OR

Comment: You were right to connect multiple paths with OR. If you want you can convert you rnext to last sentence to an answer. I would accept as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'OR' in the path condition -- `(isdescendantnode (p, [first path]) or isdescendantnode(p, [second path]))`.